# What's the quickest way to swap values of 2d array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to efficiently flip values of a 2d array from `[[a, b], [a, b], [a, b]]` to `[[b, a], [b, a], [b, a]]`

Comment: Iterate the indices and call `swapAt(0, 1)`

Comment: there isn't a faster way?

Comment: `swap` is pretty fast.

Comment: How fast are we talking? If performance is really a concern, you should be using an array of tuples or an array of SIMD values instead of an array of arrays (which involves more memory allocations and a second layer of pointer indirection)

Comment: Profile, don't speculate. Is this swapping actually a bottleneck in your program?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the map and reversed function.

As per Swift documentation

for **map** function time complexity is **O(N)**

for **reversed** - time complexity is **O(1)**

**The total time complexity is = O(N)**

```
var arr = [["a", "b"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b"]]
arr = arr.map { $0.reversed() }
print(arr)
```